# C++: изменение символа строкового литерала

Tags: c++, c++-faq

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char* str = "qwerty";
    str[0] = '1';
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Этот код выдает ошибку access violation. В чем дело? Почему нельзя изменить символ простой не-const строки?

UPD: код сработал при такой инициализации строки: char str[]. Но в чем разница?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Строковые константы в коде могут размещаться где-то в отдельном блоке памяти (в дата-секции исполняемого файла, например), который может быть отмечен как "только для чтения". Модифицировать их нельзя, это undefined behavior. Хотя на некоторых компиляторах в некоторых осях при определённых условиях это и может работать, но полагаться на это нельзя.

Если хотите иметь модифицируемую строку, то скопируйте её или объявите как массив (не как указатель).

См. [Why is this string reversal C code causing a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1614739)

Comment: забавно, не знал о такой тонкости. Спасибо. Кстати, такое правило распространяется на динамические строки? Которые созданы с new

Comment: Нет, динамически выделенная память выделяется в куче (heap), данные в которой не являются константными.

Comment: Вот каноническая ссылка по теме: http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html Тонкость в том, что строковой литерал в C используется в двух различных значениях.

Comment: Мдэ, чем больше программируешь, тем лучше понимаешь, что мало знаешь. Спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 5):

(Оказалось, что при редактировании комментария нельзя отвлекаться дольше, чем на 5 минут!!! Пришлось в ответ...)

Кстати, нормальный крестовый компилятор (например, g++) выдаст предупреждение `deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’`  для

```
  char* str = "qwerty";
```

И вообще, при изменении на `char str[] = ...`  Вы получаете другую программу, с другим набором переменных. В первом случае у Вас в стеке указатель (4 байта для 32-бит машины) с именем `str` (или "по символическому адресу", что одно и то  же), который содержит адрес строковой константы `"qwerty"` (к вашему удивлению она оказалась в read-only области памяти), а во втором по символическому адресу `str` в стеке отвели 7 байт (qwerty + nil).

Вот эту разницу Вы и увидели при запуске.

Comment: `deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’` можно обойти так:  `char* str = (char *)"qwerty";`

Comment: @reload, в С/С++ обойти можно всё что угодно,только зачем? Вопрос, да и ответ, не об этом.

Comment: Ну вдруг кому пригодится)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй использовать

```
char str[] = "qwerty";
```

вместо

```
char* str = "qwerty";
```