# В чем заключается ошибка в строке str2[0] = str2[6]? (Заранее спасибо)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    char str[8] = { '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','\0'};
    str[0] = str[6];
    cout << str << endl;

    char *str2 = "0123456";
    str2[0] = str2[6];
    cout << str2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вероятно, у вас происходит падение при выполнении программы?

Comment: Да, это так (программа компилируется).

Comment: `char *str2 = "0123456";` даже не соберется, строковой литерал можно привести только к `char const *`.

Comment: Сборка проходит успешно

Comment: Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Ответ на ваш вопрос здесь: [Ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423860/c-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строковый литерал в C++ имеет тип `const char *`, и менять его нельзя.

Такое присваивание может завалить программу, может просто молча не выполниться, может, правда, и выполниться :)

Словом, объявляйте, если хотите менять, хотя бы так:

```
char str2[] = "0123456";
```

Comment: Строковой литерал имеет тип массива `const char`, который в свою очередь может приводится к указателю на `char`.